# PHP error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function Execute() on a non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386142/php-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-execute-on-a-non-object)

I'm quite new to php and mysql so please bear with me. I wrote this code but I'm getting the following error when I attempt to delete a record from my database:

```
<?php
require_once 'login_rankings.php';
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password,$db_database);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo "Failed to connect to database: " . $mysqli->connect_errno . ": " .
$mysqli->connect_error;
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM nfl";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
printf("Number of rows: %d.\n", $stmt->num_rows); echo "<br /><br /><br />";

if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['id']))
{
// $id = get_post('id');
$query = "DELETE FROM nfl WHERE id= :id LIMIT 1";



try{
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $_POST['id']));
}catch(Exception $e){
error_log($e->getMessage() . '\r\n',3, errors.log);
}

/* not working either
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bind_param("id", $id);
  $stmt->execute(); */
}


$rows = $stmt->num_rows;
$res = $mysqli->query($query);

for ($j = 0; $j < $rows; ++$j)
{
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
require_once 'abbrs.php';

echo <<<_END
<pre>
Last name: $row[lastname]
First name: $row[firstname]
Team: $row[team]
Position: $row[position]
Number: $row[number]
Age: $row[age]
Id: $row[id]</pre>
<form action="ranking_nfl.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="delete" value="yes" />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="$row[id]" />
<input type="submit" value="DELETE" />
</form>
_END;

}


$stmt->close();

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

> Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 24

I guess that my code is lacking a function that would fetch the 'id' result from the form? I have no clue what I should write though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up PDO and mysqli syntax.

In PDO, you can use variables like `:id` and bind them afterwards. In mysqli you have to use a question mark and you bind your variables before the `execute` statement and not by feeding it an array.

In your case (taken from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), I normally use PDO):

```
$query = "DELETE FROM nfl WHERE id= ? LIMIT 1";

try{
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['id']);
  $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Well now it makes sense. I got that small bit of code using PDO from someone, and I didn't realise it was PDO not mysqli. Thanks a lot, it's working now!